# Show which directives is being used in a page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

is there a way to show wich directives is being used in a page ?

Please, take a look at this example

```
<div>
some things ...
<mydirective></mydirective>
<mydirective1></mydirective1>
<mydirective2></mydirective2>
some things ...
</div>
```

And this is the "mydirective" html

```
<div>
<mychilddirective></mychilddirective>
<mychilddirective1></mychilddirective1>
<mychilddirective2></mychilddirective2>
</div>
```

Question 1: So, my point is, how can I show the list of directives used (like in console log or somewhere else) in this page ?

The answer for this question should be

```
mydirective, mychilddirective, mychilddirective1, 
mychilddirective2, mydirective1, mydirective2
```

Question 2: If there is a answer for question 1, is there a way to "discover" the used directives using the browser console ? Or I need that my directives have to be following some kind of pattern ? (like some attribute or something like that ...)

Answer (score 0):

Every directive has link functions. That are called in a sequence. You can use them to identify which directive is being used.
Here are links for more detail about link function and their calling sequence.

https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/